# Want to display Images from API to Front using authorization in asp.net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to display Images from API to Web Application

Write this In MVC

```
using (var response = await client.GetAsync("Account/UploadedImage/" + UserId, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                {
                    var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    userimglist = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<UserImage>>(apiResponse, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
                    CsImages data = new CsImages();
                    using (HttpClient client2 = APIImage.Initial())
                    {
                        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenKey);
                        using (var response2 = await client2.GetAsync("Images/DisplayImages/CompUser/" + userimglist[0].ImageName, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                        {
                            var apiResponse2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                            data = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<CsImages>(apiResponse2, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
                        }
                    }

                    userimglist[0].ImageUrl = data.ImageUrl;
                }
```

and this in API

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("{FolderName}/{ImageName}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayImages(string FolderName, string ImageName)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine("Images\\", FolderName, ImageName);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)//check file exsit or not  
            {
                CsImages data = new CsImages();
                data.ImageUrl = "https://localhost:7119/Images/" + FolderName + "/" + ImageName;
                return Ok(data);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
```

But this will showing unauthorize in img.

I have search in google but can't find proper help.

Comment: how does your authorization pipeline look like. i mean how are you validating token ?

Comment: From the code you provided, The `DisplayImages` action provided by `[Authorize]` attribute, I don't know which kind of authentication scheme in your api project. So when you send request to this endpoint, authentication middleware will verify your identity, But in your code, you just send request without any token, So you will get 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clearly described enough. Probably you need to register [UseStaticFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in your request pipeline, if not registered yet

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
```

And here is how to authorize static files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-file-authorization

Comment: Already register the UserStaticFiles in pipeline. Here the Code                                                                  app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
})

Comment: But i'm getting 401 error when trying to display image

Answer (score 0):

Due to your question and comments I assume that you don't have implemented an Authorization Provider. You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0) official sample on how to implement one.

If you don't want to use authentification for this endpoint than remove the `[Authorize]` attribute and add `[AllowAnonymous]` instead.

If you have an Authorization Provider then please edit your question and add it.